# Is there a list of everything available at the Altar of Wishes?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

If I was the kind of person that didn't mind spoilers, where would I find a list of all things that would be available at the Altar of Wishes once I reached the maximum Dynasty rank?  I'm primarily interested in the things that will have an impact on gameplay, which means Dynasty weapons and Dynasty traits (and miscellaneous items?)

Comment: You mean other than in the game itself? You don't get new things added to the altar over time - what's there when you start playing is there for the entire game.

Comment: @Raven I'm pretty sure that isn't the case.  I believe it only shows you the things that are available at your current rank.  Both Dynasty weapons and Misc items are currently blank for me.  The dynasty page on the official site even says that increasing your *rank* (not level) will unlock new things at the Altar.

Comment: you can switch between the dynasty levels in the top right. Iron Rank (the default) simply doesn't have any items available there. Just switch the rank, and you'll see some more options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Altar of Wishes page has a drop down in the upper right corner that contains all the ranks.  As you select each rank, you can see what items are available to purchase when you obtain that rank - items you don't have the rank to obtain will be in red.

I don't know if anything ever gets added to that list as you play, but I have not seen that occur yet.

Comment: Yah, I guess I was just missing the fact that you could change ranks.